# Using tcomb-forms with React and Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, tcomb

So,

I just spent 2, gulling, days getting a tcomb-form to work with my React component, keeping options, values and the type in Redux and building part of the form after an ajax call to an API get its data.

It only now occurs to me to ask if anyone has done a reusable tcomb-forms-Redux-React component that i can do all this in so one would just inherit said component, define the type, where in redux you want to keep the state and then *poof* it just works.

Anyone?